# What are _Tp and _Up?

Tags: c++, templates, macros, stl

Inspecting the source code of STL libraries, I came across the macros _Tp and _Up that designate template variables. Where are they defined, and what is the difference between the two? Why use such macros? I couldn't find any information on this programming strategy.

**EDIT:** I am referring to the GCC STL library, and the complex class in particular, which is a templated class with contents like:

```
00115   template<typename _Tp>
00116     class complex
00117     {
00118     public:
00120       typedef _Tp value_type;
00121       
00124       complex(const _Tp& = _Tp(), const _Tp & = _Tp());
00125 
00126       // Lets the compiler synthesize the copy constructor   
00127       // complex (const complex<_Tp>&);
00129       template<typename _Up>
00130         complex(const complex<_Up>&);
00776   };
```

I'm trying to understand the copy constructor and the meaning of its comment, and decide if this is a trivially copyable class or not.

Comment: I assume you're not really looking at SGI's STL, but at your compiler's standard library implementation instead. Anything that starts with an underscore followed by a capital is reserved for the compiler & standard library, so it's an implementation detail. If you want us to help with these particular ones, you'll have to post them at the very least (and preferably state which compiler, standard library and version they're from).

Comment: I think there's a typo in that comment, it should say "_Let_ the compiler synthesize the copy constructor" i.e. it is implicitly defined. The template constructor is not the copy constructor, and there should be a blank line after the comment. I'll fix it.

Comment: @JonathanWakely Does it mean that when _Up = _Tp, the default copy constructor does not get overriden by the templated constructor?

Comment: Copy constructors must be non-templates.

Comment: The default copy constructor still exists and will be used to copy construct. The template will only get used when constructing from a different type, e.g. constructing `complex<float>` from `complex<double>`, so `_Up` can never be the same type as `_Tp`.

Comment: Thanks a lot @JonathanWakely! That's exactly what I wanted to know!

Comment: I'm going to replace the comment with a defaulted copy constructor: `complex(const complex&) = default;` (only defined for C++11 mode, but that will do a better job of documenting what's happening than the confusing comment)

Comment: The standard doesn't specify whether `complex` is always a trivially copyable type (it can be if an implementation designs it that way), but it does have one guarantee: `If z is an lvalue expression of type cv std::complex<T> then: — the expression reinterpret_cast<cv T(&)[2]>(z) shall be well-formed, — reinterpret_cast<cv T(&)[2]>(z)[0] shall designate the real part of z, and — reinterpret_cast<cv T(&)[2]>(z)[1] shall designate the imaginary part of z.` This means you can pass it to a C function expecting an array, for example. See 26.4/4.

Comment: @Simple afaik the C++ standard states that trivially copyable types cannot have user defined copy constructors. So, if the templated constructor above overloaded the default copy constructor, then complex would *not* be trivially copyable according to the definition given in the standard. But that is not the case in the specific implementation given above (GCC STL).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All names starting with an underscore followed by a capital letter are reserved for the implementation.

This is because if they used `T` instead of `_Tp`, `T` can be a user defined macro, that would break standard library.

See glibc [Reserved Names](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Reserved-Names.html):

> In addition to the names documented in this manual, reserved names include all external identifiers (global functions and variables) that begin with an underscore (‘_’) and all identifiers regardless of use that begin with either two underscores or an underscore followed by a capital letter are reserved names. This is so that the library and header files can define functions, variables, and macros for internal purposes without risk of conflict with names in user programs.

Comment: Thanks! I think I should have asked a different question because your explanation seems obvious.

Answer (score 5):

I assume you are looking at the GNU Standard Library implementation, libstdc++ used those **names** for template parameters, they are **not** macros.

Such names are reserved for the implementation (starting with an underscore, followed by a capital letter) are reserved.

e.g. (from `<functional>`)

```
  template<typename _Tp, typename _Up>
auto
_M_call(_Tp&& __object, _Up * const *) const noexcept
-> decltype((*std::forward<_Tp>(__object)).*std::declval<__pm_type&>())
{ return (*std::forward<_Tp>(__object)).*__pm; }
```

Or

```
template<typename _Tp>
struct less : public binary_function<_Tp, _Tp, bool>
{
  bool
  operator()(const _Tp& __x, const _Tp& __y) const
  { return __x < __y; }
};
```

---

**Edit:**

The same applies for the `complex` template you showed in your edit : `_Tp` design a template parameter, i.e. you can use the template as :

```
std::complex<double> c1;
std::complex<float> c2;
```

Comment: Thanks! The answer seems quite trivial indeed. I think I should have asked a different question, related to the last sentence of my edit...